# Derivative of product tensor (or matrix product )

Tags: derivatives, tensors

if I define a "product tensor" of two second-order tensors as the second-order tensor:
$\boldsymbol{C}=\boldsymbol{AB}$ such that $C_{ij}=A_{ik}B_{kj}$ does the product rule applies to $\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol{C}}{\partial\boldsymbol{X}}$ with $\boldsymbol{X}$ another second-order tensor ? If so, how and how do I prove it?

The question can be more specific:

I have a tensor valued function of tensor argument $\boldsymbol{n(x)}$. Both $\boldsymbol{n}$ and $\boldsymbol{x}$ are symmetric. I've found that $\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol{n}^2}{\partial\boldsymbol{x}}=2\boldsymbol{n}\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol{n}}{\partial\boldsymbol{x}}$ with $\boldsymbol{n}^2$ the product tensor $\boldsymbol{nn}$ and the last term is the left multiplication of $\boldsymbol{n}$ for the fourth-order tensor $\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol{n}}{\partial\boldsymbol{x}}$. How can I prove it?

Comment: what do you mean by $\frac{\partial C}{\partial X}$?

Comment: the derivative of $\boldsymbol{C}$ with respect to $\boldsymbol{X}$